# Wine opening game on wrong monitor - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine

I've just finished installing Wine (1.6.2) and subsequently got Osu! running (a music game), and while everything's running fine the game is opening on the wrong monitor in a 3 monitor setup. Some (hopefully) relevant info:

1. In order to get Osu! running correctly I had to enable the 'emulate a virtual desktop' option in the Wine config settings, specifying my required resolution (1920 x 1080).
2. From left to right I have 3 monitors, 1920 x 1080, 1920 x 1080 (primary), 1600 x 900.
3. Prior to enabling the 'virtual desktop' option Osu! would open on my primary monitor without issue.

Now however Osu opens on my lefthand monitor (1920 x 1080) by default, and I can't figure out how to get it to open on my middle (primary) monitor.

My quick and dirty solution thus far is to simply rearrange the display order in my display settings in order to get it to run on the correct display, however as I'm sure you can appreciate this is neither elegant nor preferable.

I'm admittedly unfamiliar with Wine (and Ubuntu to a point), and so if anyone could offer some advice as to how I can get Wine to open Osu! on my primary display again I'd much appreciate it?

Comment: Try setting the DISPLAY environmental variable. Typically your DISPLAY will be :0 , but with 3 monitors you likely have :0.0 , :0.1 , and :0.2 so ... `DISPLAY=:0.1 wine ....` try :0.2 and/or :0.0 as well

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - My apologies for the late reply. 

I tried setting the variable as suggested but either I did something wrong or there's something else at play. I used the following command:

`DISPLAY=:0.1 wine /home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Osu\!/osu\!.exe`.

Without the `DISPLAY=:0.1` at the start the command works fine to launch Osu!. 

I won't pretend to understand what the output code is after running the above command, so if you wish to see it for yourself let me know and I'll be more than happy to oblige?

Comment: If the output is long, use pastebin. If there is a short obvious error post it here. Open a new terminal and `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: @Panther: `DISPLAY=:0.1 wine Hearthsone.exe` fail with [next error](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/572912). Can you help how to fix?

Comment: Not use, can you open a new terminal and post the output of `echo $DISPLAY`

Answer (score 0):

Click inside wine window and use Shift+Super+*Arrow*. Works on Gnome Desktop to send window to another display. *Arrow* can be left/right/up/down according to your layout.